# How do I relabel monitors on Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, display

I'm using 2 identical Acer Technologies 24" displays connected to my laptop by HTML, running Ubuntu 22.04 with Ubuntu Pro enabled.

It would be helpful if I could relabel the monitors,Acer Left and Acer Right.

Seems like it's something basic but I just can't find the answer.

Thank you,

Greg

Comment: Since you mention Ubuntu Pro, I'm assuming you're using Ubuntu Desktop (which uses the GNOME Desktop environment). If you're using a different flavor of Ubuntu (such as Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.) with Ubuntu Pro enabled, it would be helpful to know what flavor you're using, as the answer to this question is likely going to be different depending on what desktop environment you're using.

Comment: @ArrayBolt3 As I said, I'm using Ubuntu (desktop) 22.04 with Ubuntu Pro enabled using the GNOME Desktop environment. I just noticed that when using Loom, a video recording extension for Chrome, no matter which of the two Acer Technologies displays I select, it'll only record the right screen, even though the two monitors have different content.